# how to override class methods using javascript proxy

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-proxy

this is my class

```
class Chrome {
  constructor(browser, page) {
    this.browser;
    this.page;
  }

  async launch() {
    if (!this.browser) {
      console.log("launching browser...");
      this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 200 });
    }
    if (!this.page) {
      console.log("creating page...");
      this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
    }
  }

  async navigate(url) {
    await this.launch();
    await this.page.goto(url);
  }

  async log(text) {
    console.log(text);
  }


}

class Bot extends Chrome {
  constructor(browser, page) {
    super(browser, page);
  }

  async navigateFirstPage() {
    this.log("navigating first page");
    await this.navigate("http://scraper-playground.surge.sh/#/");
  }
}

module.exports = Bot;
```

This is my index file

```
const Bot = require("./Bot");

const UsePlugin = new Proxy(new Bot(), {
  get: function(object, prop) {

    object.page && object.page.screenshot({ path: "before.jpg" });

    return object[prop];
  }
});

UsePlugin.navigateFirstPage();
```

I want to take a screenshot before and after every action. for example before navigating to a page I want to take a screenshot using `page.screenshot`. so, somehow I need to take screenshot when `navigateFirstPage()` is called.

and I need to take screenshot before and after of every action! so that, if I call `UsePlugin.anotherAction()` it should also take 2 screenshot.

how to do this inside javascript proxy's get trap?

Comment: Whats wrong with the method your currently using?

Comment: it takes a screenshot but it is a blank screen.
and most importanty..

on console, I see,

`navigating first page
launching browser...
creating page...`

it is stuck on creating page..

Comment: well, I think It is expected to stuck to creating page... as I am logging it.

so, page is created , but question is why it is captured blank screen.

I need blank screenshot first, but after the `navigateFirstPage` method is finished, I need another screenshot of actual page (not blank page)

Comment: Don't use a proxy for this. Introduce a simple adapter class to wrap the bot, or even monkey-patch it.

Comment: `class Bot extends Chrome` is a weird design choice. A bot *uses* a chrome instance, it should not inherit from one. Use composition instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proxy factory where you can target a specific method and call a callback before and after that method.

```js
function createProxy<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, methodName: K, onBefore = () => {}, onAfter = () => {}): T {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      if (prop === methodName) {
        return function (...args: any[]) {
          onBefore();
          Reflect.apply(target[prop], this, args);
          onAfter();
        };
      }

      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    },
  });
}
```

[Test it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0wFl5IAsB7AEwAoBKNTLaYIgOwiJHgDoQiBzMgchKIBLBl2gArIgCNeFANw0AvuiXoAZgFcGwJIMZ0ATvDBJ4ABX1EAHgE8APLGjxLJhiRhSx8bQBpoAaUdneFcYAGt4ayJVOAA+Mg8ALjhfAFt8YhIAOTA0pL9fRgAheFUiQ2gAXmhKSpi0BQKGAEFVE31K6qoKutQFCiSHDCxDJHV9BmgGeAB3aHMra3jJMV8h2i58MiQwfQ2kXwAHCwPfQ2B4QQA3eH0qNdpoQWiyI6IDyoqqtMJSbLS7mgPYb4MYTDRaHR6MhsGE7LgQJJgBjWADaAF0AUCgUUSmV4JR5FiHgAlEqsbRsMAHA4gRbbXb4FGvA5o3yEQQQXxwiByQFExgtNoEvkPBSEoEqLEjUHQUmqclINh7LZw-CHY6nLwXa63cVYBqKXkqehMFAmZAdKazBDIYXoE0W142G0oKrAQzGMwWGxkGjm-Y0Xi4dKkXjeGg1brUB4OljsTg8XgAYTAIFYJGgklxhhk4oNWEjPT5sdYHG4fBTafgGbArRuucU6F56Cd1hdlLwP3IvKAA)